# How to connect the MySQL query with Power BI component

Tags: powerbi

I used below MySQL query in Advanced database connection of Power BI to get the **best service station**,

```
SELECT 
C.service_station_name,
SUM(CASE
    WHEN B.status = 'Closed' THEN DATEDIFF(B.updated_at, B.created_at)
    ELSE DATEDIFF(SYSDATE(), B.created_at)
    END) AS days,
    count(B.status) as issues
FROM
    customers B
INNER JOIN
   ascs C on B.asc_id=C.id WHERE
   status = 'closed' group by service_station_name order by issues desc,days 
   asc limit 1;
```

And I used Power BI components for the other categories .
But, when I click the Power BI components, the sql Component is not getting changed. Suggest a solution to change the sql component based on Power BI component.